# Cycle in beans in other classes than Application.java

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, mybatis

I have some strange situation (with `spring-boot`):
I have a cycle in beans, but in `Application.java` (`main with        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)`) there is no cycle.  In other classes (where cycles happens) I annotate class with `@Configuration`

How does it possible ?
These beans are:

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my2")
    @PostConstruct
    @Bean
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource2() {
        return ...
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my1")
    @PostConstruct
    @Bean
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource1() {
        return ...
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RoutingDataSource dataSource() {
        RoutingDataSource rDS= new RoutingDataSource();
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1);

        Map<Object, Object> tds = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        tds.put("my2", dataSource2);
        tds.put("my1", dataSource1);
        rDS.setTargetDataSources(tds );
        return rDS;
    }
```

**Edit**

```
@Configuration
class DataConfig {  
     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my2")
        @PostConstruct
        public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource2() {
            return ...
        }

        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my1")
        @Bean
        public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource1() {
            return ...
        }

        @DependOn(value = {"dataSource2", "dataSource1"})
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public RoutingDataSource dataSource() {
            RoutingDataSource rDS= new RoutingDataSource();
            routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1);

            Map<Object, Object> tds = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
            tds.put("my2", dataSource2);
            tds.put("my1", dataSource1);
            rDS.setTargetDataSources(tds );
            return rDS;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using postconstruct annotation to initialize your datasource bean, @Bean annotation is sufficient to this scenario.

Comment: No, there even in Application class I got cycle between datasource1, dataSource2 and DataSourcInitializer

Comment: Why do you have `@PostConstruct` on `@Bean` methods... Don't do that... Also looks like you are wiring the datasources into the configuration class which basically means that the datasources are needed for construction of the configuration that actually needs them.

Comment: @M.Deinum because I have a problem with this: Could you show some example how should I do this ?

Comment: I suggest naming the bean as the classifiers in your `tds` map and add a `Map<String, DataSource>` as a method argument for the `dataSource` bean.

Comment: " suggest naming the bean as the classifiers in your" What does it mean ?

Comment: Remove the @PostConstruct annotations. Post your exact code. Because whatever you wrote won't even work as you're referencing dataSource1 and dataSource2 as variables/fields which are not in your sample snippet.

Comment: Ok, now it is better. I removed @PostConstruct, I am able to move these datasource to other class with `@Configuration`. So it is a big effect. I edited and pasted new version of code in my question.